# Sliding Sidebar trouble

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to have a sidebar slide from right to left on the homepage of my website. The hamburger menu is functioning as expected and opening the sidebar correctly however, when i click the X (close-sidebar) i am left with a long narrow column of the sidebar, and the sidebar is still showing instead of being hidden. I'm rather confused because i have the width of the sidebar (container) set to 0 upon clicking the X. I've read several answers but still seem to be stuck. any help is appreciated.

here is the jquery i was using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#btn1").click(function(){ 
        $("#box").animate({width: "350px"}); 
    }); 
    $("#btn2").click(function(){ 
        $("#box").animate({width:0}); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with  "on"
ex: $( "button" ).on( "click", notify );

Comment: I have not. I will give that a shot. I'm brand new with jquery so any further explanation are very helpful. thank you